# Issues with outputs in C using struct and stdin

Tags: c, struct, stdin

I am currently working on a computer science assignment and have come to a point I cannot work out. I have been supplied with code which I am to edit to do certain things which I have been able to do up until now, but I cannot seem to get the next bit. The code reads a number of students names and ages from standard inputs, until terminated by EOF (control D or such), constructing a linked list of them. One student is read from each input line.
My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80      // The longest line this program will accept
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 500    // The maximum number of students this program can handle
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50        // The maximum allowable name length

// The declaration of the student record (or struct). Note that
// the struct contains the name as an array of characters, rather than
// containing just a pointer to the name as before.

typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    Student* next;              // Pointer to next student in a list
};

// Create a pool of student records to be allocated on demand

Student studentPool[MAX_NUM_STUDENTS];  // The student pool
int firstFree = 0;

// Return a pointer to a new student record from the pool, after
// filling in the provided name and age fields. Returns NULL if
// the student pool is exhausted.
Student* newStudent(const char* name, int age) {
    Student* student = NULL;
    if (firstFree < MAX_NUM_STUDENTS) {
        student = &studentPool[firstFree];
        firstFree += 1;
        strncpy(student->name, name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        student->name[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Make sure it's terminated
        student->age = age;
        student->next = NULL;
    }
    return student;
}

// Read a single student from a csv input file with student name in first column,
// and student age in second.
// Returns: A pointer to a Student record, or NULL if EOF or an invalid
// student record is read. Blank lines, or lines in which the name is
// longer than the provided name buffer, or there is no comma in the line
// are considered invalid.
Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    Student* student = NULL;       // Pointer to a student record from the pool

    // Read a line, extract name and age

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {           // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the name
            student = newStudent(buffer, age);
        }
    }
    return student;
}

// Reads a list of students from a given file. Input stops when
// a blank line is read, or an EOF occurs, or an illegal input
// line is encountered.
// Returns a pointer to the first student in the list or NULL if no
// valid student records could be read.
Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;     // Pointer to the first student in the list
    Student* last = NULL;      // Pointer to the last student in the list
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;   // Empty list case
        }
        else {
            last->next = student;
            last = student;
        }
        student= readOneStudent(file);
    }
    return first;
}

// printOneStudent: prints a single student, passed by value
void printOneStudent(Student student)
{
    printf("%d (%s)\n", student.age, student.name);
}


// printStudents: print all students in a list of students, passed
// by reference
void printStudents(const Student* student)
{
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE* inputFile = stdin;
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
    }
    else {
        Student* studentList = readStudents(inputFile);
        printStudents(studentList);
    }
}
```

What the code is required to do is to take a list of inputs such as:

```
21, Fred Nurk
92, Arwen Evensong
```

And return a list of the students as follows:

```
Fred Nurk (21)
Arwen Evensong (92)
```

However my code returns:

```
 0 (21)
 0 (92)
```

And I cannot work out why. The input is set and cannot be changed, any edits to the problem have to be done to the code exclusively.

Comment: Your code is assumed as `Fred Nurk, 21`

Comment: Your code in `readOneStudent()` is assuming that the age follows the comma and the name appears before the comma.  This contradicts what you said you're actually working with as input.  Make the input and the code match and you're in with a chance of it all working.

Comment: To OP and the author of [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9076096), unlike other sites, [we don't add thanks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), or stuff that adds nothing to the question like [I'm relative new to ...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135619/is-it-correct-to-edit-a-question-to-remove-a-verbose-introduction).

Comment: `printf("%d (%s)\n", student.age, student.name);` --> `printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);`

Comment: Perhaps running this through a debugger will help you no end. I can see one error in newStudent(), this wouldn't be your main issue, - however I feel you should at least have a go. Trace it through with a debugger and this will help you understand what is going on and also what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your function `Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file);`, you are expecting input in this format:

```
Fred Nurk,21
Arwen Evensong,92
```

If you want your input to be in this form:

```
21, Fred Nurk
92, Arwen Evensong
```

then this might help:

```
Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char *buffer;  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    buffer = (char *)malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
    Student* student = NULL;       // Pointer to a student record from the pool

    // Read a line, extract name and age

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {           // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the age part
            int age = atoi(buffer);
            student = newStudent(commaPos+2, age);
        }
    }
    return student;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
void printOneStudent(Student student)
{
    printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
}
```

Comment: Hi again, thank you so much for the help, it works nearly perfectly :) I was wondering however if you would know how to change the output from what it is using this (\n indicates where a new line occurs):
    `name 1\n`
    `(age 1) name 2\n`
    `(age 2)`

and instead have it return in the format:

    `name 1 (age 1)\n`
    `name 2 (age 2)`

Comment: You are getting this type of output because there's `'\n'` at the end of name. Overwrite it with `'\0'` character. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let us inspect the following code snippet

```
Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    Student* student = NULL;       // Pointer to a student record from the pool

// Read a line, extract name and age

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {           // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the name
            student = newStudent(buffer, age);
        }
    }
    return student;
}
```

According to you, the input should be:

> age,name

The following line finds the address of the comma separator

```
char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
```

And the age is being extracted by the following line:

```
int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
```

So it takes the address of the comma separator and increments by 1

> age,[n]ame

Thus your assumption is incorrect. The input should be the reversed order

> name,age

And the output will be

> age (name)

Edit:
To swap the input form just swap to the following in Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file):

```
int age = atoi(buffer);
student = newStudent(commaPos + 1, age);
```

And to swap the output form in void printOneStudent(Student student):

```
printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
```

Comment: The point of the problem was that we were given the input, and had to rewrite our code to comply with the input. Sorry I should have made that clearer in the examples :)

Comment: Basically you want to change input from "name,age" to "age,name". and output from "age (name)" to "name (age)" ?

Comment: Did you even try to perform the changes? I mean before posting this issue in SO. Cause in ur post I cannot see that .. :P